# passing variables from fancybox to parent / iframe to parent

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

trying to access content in iframe (fancybox) . i have tried all methods but i get either null or undefined.

```
$(".editdata").live('click', function() {
            var editdata_class=$(this).attr('class');
             var editdata_id=$(this).attr('id');
            alert(editdata_class);

               $.fancybox({
                 'width': 800,
                 'height': 700,
                 'type': 'iframe',
                 href:'forgotpass.php?class_data='+editdata_class+'&id_data='+editdata_id,
                    onClosed : function() {

                        var bla =$("#fancybox-frame").contents().find('#personalsizeleft').html();
                            alert(bla);
                      alert(editdata_id);
                      $('#'+editdata_id).append('hello');
                    }
                   })

             });
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong ???

Comment: jsut to let you know i have gone done most things mentioned in other stack overflow posts and jquery posts...have tried using  accessing 'iframe content from parent' ?  could it be that the iframe is created only when we clikc on the duv tag and is removed when the onclose event takes place hence it can see the iframe tag ? if that is the case then how does read content from a fancybox and send it across to the parent

Comment: solved it ...  onCleanup: function() {
                         var bla =$("#fancybox-frame").contents().find('html body').html();
                            alert(bla);
                            var bla =$("#fancybox-content").contents().find('#personalsizeleft').html();  alert(bla);
                   
                    },   
so write it to the parent window and then on close read it again... if required...

Comment: post your solution as an answer and then mark it as correct so this question won't appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

```
onCleanup: function() { 
     var bla =$("#fancybox-frame").contents().find('html body').html(); alert(bla); 
     var bla =$("#fancybox-content").contents().find('#personalsizeleft').html();        
     alert(bla); },
```

so write it to the parent window and then on close read it again... if required.